# Asp.net (c#) and a Java EE 5 web service

Tags: java, asp.net, web-services

We have a asp.net app that talks to a pretty complex Java EE 5 web service.  Everything works fine except when we throw an exception.  We throw a simple exception without any inner/orig exception, but we get this message on the .Net side.

```
Additional XML content is present in the fault detail element. Only a single element is allowed.
```

Works fine with a java client, as in we can get the exception message.  What can we do?

Comment: Clarification, the JEE 5 web service throws the exception and .net can't decipher.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/14a2c1a3-d277-41ef-86f8-0ddb18f0beec

Comment: We found that and our .net developer says he couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score -1):

Nicholas Allen talks about this in his bog post [Writing Multiple Detail Elements in Faults](http://blogs.msdn.com/drnick/archive/2008/04/03/writing-multiple-detail-elements-in-faults.aspx):

> On the reverse side, you'll have exactly the same problem with GetDetail because it too is limited to a single object. In this case though, you have the replacement directly accessible, GetReaderAtDetailContents, and are more likely to already have been using it.